# Want to update a column with a number value following specific query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

So this is my first question and first day here. Thanks in advance.

I want to perform the following query -

Put the fine on books_return if the duration is violated, otherwise put zero.
The duration is in book_issue. SO I figured out that I can calculate the difference between return_date and issue_date and if it is greater than 10 then fine_amount will update to 20; otherwise will update to zero. However, I am having trouble with the query statement which is the following -

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT brt.fine_amount 
    FROM book_return brt, book_issue bi 
    WHERE brt.book_id = bi.book_id 
        AND brt.return_date - bi.issue_date > bi.issue_duration
) SET fine_amount = 20;
```

---

```
error - ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

How can I pull off this query?

EDIT: book_id and borrower_id are the composite primary keys of both tables.

related tables -

[image]

Comment: The setup seems incorrect. `book_id`, presumably, is the id of a book; the same book is checked out multiple times, so which return corresponds to each check-out? Instead of joining on `book_id`, your tables must have a different `id` to identify the specific lending (check-out) transaction. The way it is now, if you don't have such a separate id, it's not clear how to solve your problem.

Comment: Umm, that totally went above my head. See, the problem is I am a college student and this is my assignment. I am new to DBMS. My teacher is quite a work and he didn't give me any hint about how to solve this. I just learned about "update" 30 mins ago of posting this question. I can skip this query to complete my assignment but I kinda want to solve it. Can you simplify your comment a little bit so that I can understand? Sorry if I am a mess.

I think I did unique checkouts here. book_id and borrower_id are the composite primary keys of both tables.

Comment: Then use `borrower_id` to do the join, in addition to `book_id`. If that is indeed a primary key, that is EXACTLY what Oracle needs (the "key-preserved table" thing in the error message is exactly about that).

Comment: ok understood. Thanks

Comment: How can `book_id`/`borrower_id` be a composite primary key of either table?  Does the library limit a borrower to borrowing any given book a maximum of one time?

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with `merge`.  If you use `update`, you can use `exists`:

```
UPDATE book_return brt
    SET fine_amount = 20
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM book_issue bi 
                  WHERE brt.book_id = bi.book_id AND
                        brt.return_date - bi.issue_date > bi.issue_duration
                 );
```

Comment: Please see the Comments to see why this will not work any more than the OP's solution (and to see the proper way to approach it).

Comment: Thanks, the code worked! Can you provide me any explanation of this code (the exists part and onwards select 1 and stuff)? It's ok to provide me with a link to the necessary information as well. I have no problem with reading.

Side question, this updated the values where I needed to add 20. But the rest needs to be modified with a zero. So hat should I do? use case statement?

example -
SET fine_amount = (case when brt.return_date - bi.issue_date > bi.issue_duration then 20
                        when brt.return_date - bi.issue_date < bi.issue_duration then 0
                   end)

Comment: @Sanb_213 - "the query didn't result in an error" is not the same thing as "the query worked." This solution will pick up the oldest issue date for each book (regardless of who the borrower was). There is no matching by `borrower_id`.